# Enable External Sharing Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, provider-hosted-app

We have a scenario on which we are creating site collections from a provider-hosted app. Some of these site collections will be used by external users. Is there a way from CSOM (server-side) to enable external sharing on the site collection? I haven't found any resources stating whether this is or not doable.

I'm trying to replicate the settings you can specify at the site collections page on the tenant admin site:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very possible look at the code provided by the office pnp team here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/master/OfficeDevPnP.Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/AppModelExtensions/TenantExtensions.cs#L414

```
    public static void SetSiteProperties(this Tenant tenant, string siteFullUrl,
        string title = null,
        bool? allowSelfServiceUpgrade = null,
        SharingCapabilities? sharingCapability = null,
        long? storageMaximumLevel = null,
        long? storageWarningLevel = null,
        double? userCodeMaximumLevel = null,
        double? userCodeWarningLevel = null
        )
    {
        var siteProps = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(siteFullUrl, true);
        tenant.Context.Load(siteProps);
        tenant.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
        if (siteProps != null)
        {
            if (allowSelfServiceUpgrade != null)
                siteProps.AllowSelfServiceUpgrade = allowSelfServiceUpgrade.Value;
            if (sharingCapability != null)
                siteProps.SharingCapability = sharingCapability.Value;
            if (storageMaximumLevel != null)
                siteProps.StorageMaximumLevel = storageMaximumLevel.Value;
            if (storageWarningLevel != null)
                siteProps.StorageWarningLevel = storageMaximumLevel.Value;
            if (userCodeMaximumLevel != null)
                siteProps.UserCodeMaximumLevel = userCodeMaximumLevel.Value;
            if (userCodeWarningLevel != null)
                siteProps.UserCodeWarningLevel = userCodeWarningLevel.Value;
            if (title != null)
                siteProps.Title = title;

            siteProps.Update();
            tenant.Context.ExecuteQueryRetry();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I was looking at the Site object.